# Cannot ProcessBuilder to execute command for ffmpeg -i shortWav.wav -af silenceremove=1:0:-50dB shortWavCued.mp3

Tags: java, bash

Hi having problems trying to run a bash command using via java ProcessBuilder command construction route.

I decided against using Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command) due to file not found errors. Found that was due to it naively trying to parse the command.

The bash command i want to execute is

```
ffmpeg -i shortWav.wav -af silenceremove=1:0:-50dB shortWavCued.mp3
```

When passing in the command i have tried a variation

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("ffmpeg", "-i " + source + "-af" + "silenceremove" +"1", "0" + "-50dB" + target);
```

The part of the bash command that i'm stuck on is

```
silenceremove=1:0:-50dB
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside: You are not actually trying to run a bash command. bash is a shell, and `ProcessBuilder` is NOT a shell nor does it run a shell automatically (like C's `system()` does), although you can run a shell explicitly if you want to. You are trying to run a *program* with arguments in the same fashion that a shell command would run that same program with arguments.

Each argument to the program, that bash would form by splitting at unquoted whitespace (and modifying in some cases not present here) must be a separate argument to ProcessBuilder, and when you want punctuation within one argument you must provide it. One possibility:

```
new ProcessBuilder("ffmpeg" , "-i" , source , "-af" , "silenceremove=" + "1" + ":0" + ":-50db" , target)
# extra spaces around , and + added for clarity can be removed if you prefer
```

Variations like `"silenceremove" + "="` ... are also possible.

Although many commands don't work with `Runtime.exec`'s naive parsing (break at *all* whitespace, not just unquoted) this one should have.

Comment: yes sorry i know bash is not a command. it was late and I was tired. I will give those a try. thanks