# Run nodejs using java

Tags: java, node.js

I need to run some node.js program using java

my code looks like this

```
String filePath= "/home/gilles/eclipse-workspace/informationGewinnungApp/videotool/src/videotool.js";
    String option1 = "-m resources/WetterBerich";
    String option2 = "--bg_content resources/logo.png";

    ProcessBuilder Pb =
               new ProcessBuilder("node",filePath+option1+option2);
             Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
             env.put("VAR1", "myValue");
             env.remove("OTHERVAR");
             env.put("VAR2", env.get("VAR1") + "suffix");
             pb.directory(new File("/usr/bin"));
             File log = new File("log");
            // pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
             pb.redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
             pb.redirectOutput(Redirect.appendTo(log));
             Process p = pb.start();
             assert pb.redirectInput() == Redirect.PIPE;
             assert pb.redirectOutput().file() == log;
             assert p.getInputStream().read() == -1;
```

but I get this Error

```
module.js:549
throw err;
^
```

Answer (score 0):

Mostly dupe: [Cannot ProcessBuilder to execute command for ffmpeg -i shortWav.wav -af silenceremove=1:0:-50dB shortWavCued.mp3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51487919/cannot-processbuilder-to-execute-command-for-ffmpeg-i-shortwav-wav-af-silencer)

**You are putting multiple (all) options in ONE argument.**

When you give a command line `node this that` to a shell, it passes `this` and `that` to node as separate arguments, and that is how node expects to receive them. `ProcessBuilder` does not split strings into separate arguments like a shell does, you must do it:

```
ProcessBuilder Pb = new ProcessBuilder("node",filePath, 
  "-m", "resources/WetterBerich",
  "--bg_content", "resources/logo.png");
```

PS: using `/usr/bin` for your working directory is typically not a good idea.